# Ajax GET request with authorization header and CORS on android 2.3.3

Tags: android, ajax, oauth, oauth-2.0, cors

I'm attempting to make a cross domain GET request on android 2.3.3. I'm using CORS Filter on the server. I have tested this on chrome, firefox, iphone and it works fine. With android 2.3.3 the preflight request looks good, but **the actual request isn't sending the Origin header**. I'm getting the data back just fine but the ajax errors out with a status 0. I tried changing it to a POST request and that worked!!!

Here is the ajax code:

...

```
$.ajax( {
    beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
        xhr.withCredentials = true;
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer myoathtoken');
    },
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    url: getMyUrl() + '/data.json',
    success: function(data) {
        alert("It works");
    }
});
```

Here are the results for the get (**doesn't work**)

```
OPTIONS http://test2.mydomain:9990/data.json HTTP/1.1
Host: test2.mydomain:9990
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Language: en-US
Access-Control-Request-Headers: Authorization, Accept
Cookie: mycookie=mycookieval
Accept-Charset: utf-8, iso-8859-1, utf-16, *;q=0.7
Referer: http://test.mydomain:9990/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.3; en-us; sdk Build/GRI34)         AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
Origin: http://test.mydomain:9990
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Accept: text/xml, text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/png, text/plain, */*;q=0.8

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://test.mydomain:9990
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: HEAD, GET, OPTIONS, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, X-Requested-With, Origin, Accept, Content-Type
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 03 Feb 2012 21:29:05 GMT

GET http://test2.mydomain:9990/data.json HTTP/1.1 
Host: test2.mydomain:9990
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Referer: http://test.mydomain:9990/
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.3; en-us; sdk Build/GRI34)        AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
Cookie: mycookie=mycookieval
Authorization: Bearer oauthtoken
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Charset: utf-8, iso-8859-1, utf-16, *;q=0.7

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 03 Feb 2012 21:29:08 GMT
```

Here are the result for sending a post (**works**)

```
OPTIONS http://test2.mydomain:9990/data.json HTTP/1.1
Host: test2.mydomain:9990
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Language: en-US
Access-Control-Request-Headers: Authorization, Accept
Cookie: mycookie=mycookieval
Accept-Charset: utf-8, iso-8859-1, utf-16, *;q=0.7
Referer: http://test.mydomain:9990/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.3; en-us; sdk Build/GRI34) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
Origin: http://test.mydomain:9990
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Accept: text/xml, text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/png, text/plain, */*;q=0.8

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://test.mydomain:9990
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, POST, HEAD, GET
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, X-Requested-With, Origin, Accept, Content-Type
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 03 Feb 2012 21:21:30 GMT

POST http://test2.mydomain:9990/data.json HTTP/1.1
Host: test2.mydomain:9990
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Language: en-US
Cookie: mycookie=mycookieval
Authorization: Bearer oauthtoken 
Accept-Charset: utf-8, iso-8859-1, utf-16, *;q=0.7
Referer: http://test.mydomain:9990/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.3; en-us; sdk Build/GRI34) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
Origin: http://test.mydomain:9990
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Content-Length: 0

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://test.mydomain:9990
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 03 Feb 2012 21:21:32 GMT
```

I did a little more testing and took the authorization header out of equation and it worked with doing a GET. Not sure why the authorization header would cause it to fail for get requests. Any ideas?

Comment: I've created a simple test page to test CORS requests. Can you try your request out in Android and see what the response is: http://client.cors-api.appspot.com/client?server.enable=true&server.httpstatus=200&server.methods=GET&server.headers=Authorization&client.method=GET&client.headers.Authorization=Test

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Sending GET request to http://server.cors-api.appspot.com/server? id=6058740&httpstatus=200&methods=GET&headers=Authorization , with custom headers 
Fired XHR event: loadstart 
Fired XHR event: readystatechange 
Fired XHR event: error

XHR status: 0 
XHR status text:

Comment: I get the same response for android 2.2, 2.3, and 3.x. For what it's worth, the console log returns this in 3.x: E/browser (  333): Console: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://server.cors-api.appspot.com/server?id=6202948&httpstatus=200&methods=GET&headers=Authorization. Origin http://client.cors-api.appspot.com is not allowed by Access-
Control-Allow-Origin. null:1

Comment: This chart indicates that CORS support should work on those Android versions: http://caniuse.com/cors Though this may be an edge case bug. I'm using Android 4.0.3 and it works. Perhaps you can just continue using POST for now?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. Yes, using post is a workaround I may end up using.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, however it is not a problem with authorization header but with the missing Origin Header in the GET request. That is also why the post request is working - there is an Origin Header and the Origin Header is mandatory for CORS.

Stange thing is that the OPTIONS Preflight call has an Origin Header set.